# What does "pirette/pyrette" mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, littérature

I came about these words ***pirette*** and ***pyrette*** twice, in two different contexts, but couldn't find any references in the dictionaries.

"Les Journaux, 31 octobre 1938. Caltez avec vos parchemins ! Arrière ! Troubadours ! Luth !
Sornettes ! Oh ! Là ! Là ! **Pirette** ! Néfaste ! Au musée ! La honte !" (L'École des cadavres, 1938)

"Ça sera fini les badinages!... C'est une poudre qu'on va découvrir au fond d'une **pyrette** diabolique" (Guignol's Band I, 1944)

Does anyone know what do these words mean? Are they synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

These are Céline's creations. I gather they were not synonyms in his mind. And they do not seem to be synonyms to a French reader.

The first instance could either be a proper noun (Pirette can be a surname) or created by Céline as in insult. If we consider the context of the paragraph I would rather think it is an insult, maybe made up to rime with the preceding *sornettes* (a real word,  3 syllables as well). In the whole paragraph even words that are not usually insults (*fripe*, *défroque*, etc.) are used as insults. And the whole is made up for a comic effect. If it is used as an insult grammatically it is an interjection, therefore it is not a noun.

The word *pyrette* in the second instance is grammatically a noun (fem.). There's no such word in French. Considering the context (*poudre/au fond de* and in reference to the paragraph *sortilèges, philtre(ries)*, etc.) it could call to mind the word *pipette*.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Je viens de trouver une note dans l'édition de la Pléiade. Godard propose que "pirette" et "pyrette" sont des synonymes : "Le mot énigmatigue de pyrette reparaît dans Guignol's Band II sous la forme pyrète. Il figurait dans L'École des cadavres, sous la forme pirette. Dans les trois cas, il semble désigner un instrument ou récipient utilisé en chimie ou en alchimie, sans doute, si l'on en croit les graphies en y en relation avec le feu, et sans rapport avec le pyrèthre qui est une plante." 
Pensez-vous qu'il s'agit d'une interprétation plausible ?

Comment: L'interprétation est plausible, mais toute interprétation est plausible dans le cas de la création artistique. Céline peut très bien avoir réutilisé le mot et pris un nom commun pour en faire une interjection. Je vois que Godard relie comme moi pyrette à pipette (chimie), par contre je suis sceptique sur la relation avec le feu, mais comme nous sommes dans le domaine de l'interprétation tout avis est personnel. Et je ne vois pas comment relier à la pyrèthre (la fleur).